# Is it possible to add second where condition to select this same data but from other date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I have two tables in SQL Server.

[image]

I want to select DeptCode, DeptName, YearToDate, PeriodToDate (2 months for example) and group it by DeptCode.
There is a result which I want to get:

[image]

- In YTD column I want to get sum of totalCost since 01/01/actualYear.
- In PTD column I want to get the sum from last two months.

I created a piece of code which shows me correct YTD cost but I don't know how I can add next one for getting total cost for other date range. Is it possible to do this?

```
SELECT  
    d.DeptCode,
    d.DeptName,
    SUM(s.TotalCost) as YTD
FROM [Departments] AS d
INNER JOIN Shipments AS s
ON d.DeptCode= s.DeptCode
WHERE s.ShipmentDate BETWEEN DateAdd(yyyy, DateDiff(yyyy, 0, GetDate()), 0) 
AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY d.DeptCode, d.DeptName
```

Comment: There are three parts to the exercise: (1) write an expression which specifies the start of the period for the PTD summation; (2) generate SQL which generates the sum over the period from start of period to today; and (3) process the results correctly.  You will have to write out at least some of the summation code twice.  You can use your current expression as one sub-select in the FROM clause, your new expression as a second sub-select, and join the two and process the results.  There's probably a way to do it more directly using the OLAP functionality, assuming MS SQL Server supports that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output doesn't match 2 months, but here's the code to accomplish what you want.  You just have to add a `SUM(CASE...)` on the 2nd condition.

```
SELECT  
    d.DeptCode,
    d.DeptName,
    SUM(s.TotalCost) as YTD,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.ShipmentDate >= DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()) then s.TotalCost else 0 END) as PTD

FROM [Departments] AS d
INNER JOIN Shipments AS s
ON d.DeptCode= s.DeptCode
WHERE Year(s.ShipmentDate) = Year(GETDATE())
GROUP BY d.DeptCode, d.DeptName
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more column that returns 0 when not in the two-month range, e.g. `SUM(CASE WHEN (date check) THEN (amount) ELSE 0 END)`. Check out the fifth line:

```
SELECT  
    d.DeptCode,
    d.DeptName,
    SUM(s.TotalCost) as YTD,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DateDiff(MONTH, s.ShipmentDate, GetDate()) < 2 THEN s.TotalCost ELSE 0 END) PTD,
FROM [Departments] AS d
INNER JOIN Shipments AS s
ON d.DeptCode= s.DeptCode
WHERE s.ShipmentDate BETWEEN DateAdd(yyyy, DateDiff(yyyy, 0, GetDate()), 0) 
AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY d.DeptCode, d.DeptName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
nbr_last2month_ AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
   Sum(s.[TotalCost]) AS 'PTD', 
   s.DeptCode, 
   s.DeptName
 FROM    [Shipements] s
         LEFT JOIN [Departements] d ON d.[DeptCode] = s.[DeptCode] 
 WHERE   Year(date_) LIKE Year(GETDATE()) 
         AND MONTH(ShipementDate) LIKE Month(Getdate()) - 2
 Group by DeptCode
),

nbr_YTD_ AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
   Sum(s.[TotalCost]) AS 'YTD', 
   s.DeptCode, 
   s.DeptName
 FROM    [Shipements] s
         LEFT JOIN [Departements] d ON d.[DeptCode] = s.[DeptCode]
 WHERE    Year(ShipementDate) LIKE Year(GETDATE()) 
 Group by DeptCode
),

SELECT 
   A.DeptCode,
   A.DeptName,
   YTD,
   PTD
FROM   nbr_YTD_ A
       LEFT JOIN nbr_last2month_ B on B.DeptCode = A.DeptCode
ORDER BY DeptCode
```